# Extjs4 MultiLevelGrouping Grid and being able to print it

Tags: extjs, gridview, extjs4, extjs4.2

I was trying to print an ExtJs grid and found rahul singla post:

http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/10/extjs-printing-gridpanels-with-groupingview-and-groupsummary-plugin

which led me to Ed Spencer Printer class, wich led me to Loaine's  ExtJs4 version

https://github.com/loiane/extjs4-ux-gridprinter

which is absolutely great, so far so good, but the grid I'm trying to print has a multilevel groupingsummary feature  for wich I used this UX

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265814-Multi-level-grouping-summary-and-grand-totals-for-Ext-JS-4.2

Problems are:

1.- While this grid does get printed it doesn't recognize the grouping feature.

2.- The second time the grid with the multilevel groupingsummary feature is rendered or tried to be rendered I get "TypeError: oldGroupCache is null"

I know this stuff is too specific but hopefully somebody else is trying to acomplish the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

(I'm using ExtJs 4.2.1 and can't go to a newer version because of my work)