# How to export extjs widget-grid into PDF

Tags: extjs5

I am using Extjs5 widget-grid and want to export widget-grid into PDF.
Can any one  please provide a way for the same.

Comment: Maybe this link can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172003/extjs4-multilevelgrouping-grid-and-being-able-to-print-it

Comment: you need to return a pdf from the server, this is not possible with javascript or ExtJS